# How to remove the weird space between an Angular app end the end of the body?

Tags: html, css, angular

under my Angular app is a weird space. The Space is part of the body tag but it isn't not part of the app-root tag. How can I remove this space?

[image]

```css
/*styles.css*/
@import './styles/themes.scss';

@include mat-core();
@include angular-material-theme($material-light-theme);

.dark-theme{
    @include angular-material-color($material-dark-theme);
}

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Verdana, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

I already tried this on my App-Component but it had no effect.

```css
app-component.css
:host {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
/*app-component.scss*/
bg-intranet-header {
    z-index: 2;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

I tested it in two browsers (firefox, edge). here are 3 screenshots of the actual interpreted css.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try `min-height:100vh;` ?

Comment: yes, but it had no effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In styles.css (or styles.scss, ..) you put:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This must be in that particular file.
If it doesn't work, try:

```
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Your were faster than me, was about to post exactly this.

Comment: I already did this as you can see in my example. I tried adding the important keyword but this isn't working too.

Comment: In that case just inspect your app (like with F12 in google chrome).
Try the body element and look if there is a margin..
Maybe the elements inside your body are simply not 100% height.

Comment: I did, but cause of some weird behaviour the body and the html tag have a relative size of 100% but the html is "longer" as shown the screenshot above.

Comment: Can you post the:
styles.css
app.component.css
complete containance please so I can try locally?

I've just tried a basic angular app, and place te code in my answer in the scss file and it works as intended.. there must be some other problem.
Also mention which browser you are using please.

Comment: Also beware of using :host ::ng-deep inside your components, or also ViewEncapsulation.None. These styles leak through to other components and could be messing up your view

Comment: I updated my answer it now contains the app-component.css to

Comment: html height is 100%, but possibly there is a margin on this element, which extends it to more than 100%. Check this in browser inspect element.
If you inspect html element at the bottom (in chrome devtools), there is a box which gives all values for height, width, margins and paddings.. check there where the extra height is coming from..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css

**css**

```
body {
      margin: 0px !important;
      padding : 0px !important;
    }

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

i hope i will work fine !

Comment: Ok So now can you Please create your issue to Stakblliz ? bcz without code or files we can not say properly....

Comment: if this angular project is connected with github then you can send Repo link ! then i will fix 100%

Comment: It is a properitary project and i'm not allowed to post larger amount of source code on the internet.